# Writing a method in java using an array and objects

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, methods

I'm new to Java and I'm stuck on this problem:

"Create a second add() method which has a single parameter of an array of doubles and, inside the method, adds the values of the array, returning the result as a double. Sample test data:

```java
double[] dblArr = {11.82,88.23,33};
```

I have a separate class file with the following so far:

```java
public double add(double[] values) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (double i : values)
        sum += i;

     return sum;
}
```

This is the method to add the array's and return the total sum.

And this is the code I have in my "main" document to call the method

```java
double dblArr;
utils.print("Please enter an array of 5 numbers: ");
dblArr = input.nextDouble();

double sum = calc.add(dblArr);

System.out.println(dblArr);
```

I know I'm quite off scope so some advice would be really appreciated, thank you

"calc" is what I'm using to call the other document

Calculate calc = new Calculate();

Comment: Looks like you are calling `calc` as if it was `static`. If you don't need to create an instance of a `calc` add `static` to the front: `public static add(double[]...`

Comment: And what's the problem? What error are you getting? What's not happening as you'd expect it to? Please edit it into your post, thank you.

Comment: `int sum = 0;` should be `double sum = 0;` - and your `dblArr` should be a `double[]` (instead of a `double`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most of the way there, you just need to use a double array to gather the inputs, and you need to use a loop to save all the inpets to the array:

```
//use an array instead of a single double
double[] dblArr = new double[5];
int inputs = 0;
//Use a loop to gather 5 inputs
while(inputs < 5){
    utils.print("Please enter the next of 5 numbers: ");
    dblArr[inputs] = input.nextDouble();
    inputs++;
}

//We have changed the add method to static, so you can just use `add(dblArr)` instead of making an instance of the class with the add method
double sum = add(dblArr);

//Finally print out the sum result not the dblArr array
System.out.println("The total is " + sum);
```

Then just change the method to `static` so that you can call it directly:

```
//Add static to this line as shown, because we don't need an instance of this method
public static double add(double[] values) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (double i : values)
        sum += i;

    return sum;
}
```